# Enterprise Library ValidatorFactory

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

In these days of dependency injection, it's good to see people taking a stand against "outsiders" interfering with their class hierarchy.

In the case of Enterprise Library, the moral stand took this form:

```
public abstract class ValidatorFactory { [...]
       protected internal abstract Validator InnerCreateValidator(...); }
```

Ah, the beauties of the "internal" keyword, when applied to interfaces and abstract methods.

If you know of a way to get around this, without having to modify the Enterprise Library DLLs, please let us know.  Thanks.

Comment: [What Does Protected Internal Mean?](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/10/29/what-does-protected-internal-mean.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's declared [`protected internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) so that any code in a class **deriving** (or within the same assembly) from `ValidatorFactory` can access this member. Derive from `ValidatorFactory` and then you'll be able to access this member using code within that class. That's your solution.